# Problem in identification of seismic event?

Tags: seismology, seismic

I have taken the following synthetic seismogram, generated using Marmousi model, from the [Madagascar website](http://www.ahay.org/RSF/book/xjtu/modeling2fwi/paper_html/node11.html).
I could not understand the origin of linear events (present in shot3 after 2 sec) and similarly in shot 7 at 2sec.
Any help is appreciated.

[image]